# tooltip for checkboxGroup or radioGroup in repeat control

Tags: tooltip, xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

I have a repeat control bound to a (multi column) viewScope array.
The idea is that the chekboxGroup value will come from the first column and that the tooltip will come from the second column from the array.

The first thing (checkbox value) is not the problem. (see code)

The second thing is:
How can I assign the correct tooltip to the correct checkbox ?

```
<xp:repeat id="repeat4" rows="100" value="#{viewScope.choices}"
        indexVar="rownumber" var="row" first="0">

        <xp:checkBoxGroup id="checkBoxGroup2" layout="lineDirection">
            <xp:selectItems>
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return viewScope.choices[rownumber].get(0)}]]></xp:this.value>
            </xp:selectItems>
        </xp:checkBoxGroup>
        <xe:tooltip id="tooltip1" for="checkBoxGroup2">
            <xe:this.label><![CDATA[#{javascript:return viewScope.choices[rownumber].get(1)}]]></xe:this.label>
        </xe:tooltip>
</xp:repeat>
```

**EDIT**

It seems that the tooltips work but are displayed off screen.
How do I manage to display them at the correct spot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position="before"` or `position="above"` or `position="below"` to your tooltip control.

```
         <xe:tooltip id="tooltip1" for="checkBoxGroup2" position="before">
```

By default it is `"after"` and this is outside the visible area in your example.